# Stage3D iOS Antialiasing on AIR 24

Tags: ios, lines, antialiasing, stage3d, wireframe

With AIR 24 release we are able to set anti aliasing on Stage3D now, but there are some issues with it. Can anybody help how to use it in right way without changing entire project code ?

The issue I have is that anti alias works great, and no more jagged edges, but there are rendering issues and I guess some texture normals are being inverted, also when using Occlusion Material there are some jagged material shadows...

Next thing I notice is when drawing Wireframe Globe with Lines Segments - the lines are visible on the globe all the time, no matter if you add some object in front or not.
So, intersecting line segments with other materials don't work at all, and lines are on the screen forever.

Please, help if you find any trick fixing the issues.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some more information: the issue seems to happen when shareContext = true. Without Starling there is antialiasing and the lineSegments are rendered at the current depth. It would be interesting to see if it works with other sharedContext besides Starling to isolate the issue. If I find an answer I will come back and post it. It would be nice to get this working. Any idea the performance hit on mobile of having a second instance of away3d? Layering that way might be a dirty work around.

*****EDIT****

AntiAliasing on the line Segments only occurs with sharedContext. View3D class does not seem to have it's antiAlias value set anywhere and when I forced it to a value of 2, all hell broke loose.

Edit#2

Mesh appears above line segments, Sprite3D do not.